# Catching mysql errors in php and giving a custom response

Tags: php, mysql, try-catch

I've got a website where you can input TV series you haves watched. There are two tables, one where the title is the primary key and another table references that title as the foreign key.

Since the data is input by users who are unfamiliar to the wonders of programming, I want to try and catch the mysql error that the foreign key constraint fails, and give a response like "title not found".

I know you can try-catch blocks in Java.

I'm creating this website purely to practice my web development skills, since I'm fairly new to programming, so its not anything serious.

Comment: Have you already implemented a database structure? If so, could you please post it?

Comment: Do you mean my create table statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. It depends on the MySQL API you're using. If you're using ext/mysql, [stop using it](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). If you're using mysqli or PDO, it depends on whether you have configured both to throw exceptions (in which case `try..catch` will do) or whether the functions simply `return false` on failure, in which case you have to add error handling code as such:

```
if (!mysqli_query(...)) {
    // handle error here
}
```

To distinguish between different SQL errors, use [`mysqli_errno`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.errno.php).

Comment: Ive used only mysqli functions with php thats it, can you direct me to a guide if possible, my variables return false. So far i have done this:                                                      $insert= mysqli_query($connection, $query);


    if ($insert == false) {
 die("error: " . mysqli_error($connection));
    } else {
 mysqli_close($connection);

 echo $title . " has been inserted";
}

Comment: So, you're already 90% of the way there. Just instead of `die()`, do something more useful.

Comment: Yes, but the thing is, $insert could be false for multiple reasons, for example, if the user tries to insert the same title twice, it would throw a "duplicate entry for primary key" error, and i wouldn't be able to distinguish between the two using the current if condition

Comment: You're looking for `mysqli_errno()` to get the specific error code.